# Open pdf file from raw folder in PDF Reader

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-fragments

I have some problem. I try to make one thing that when user press on the button, the pdf file opens in PDF Reader. I write everything in program, but it doesn't work. What is the problem? Can you write me a code correctly? I do everything in fragement. My code:

```
package lt.sviesioji.kdainiviesiojigimnazija;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FormulynasFragment extends Fragment {

public FormulynasFragment() {
}

Button f;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int backButtonCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (backButtonCount > 0) {
        Fragment newFragment = new PagrindinisFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_formulynas, container,
            false);

    f = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button69);
    f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.matematika);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startpdf();
        }
        private void startpdf() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File file = new File("R.id.matematika");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

First, `R.id.matematika` is not a file. That is the ID of a resource. A resource is a file only on your development machine. `new File("R.id.matematika")` is meaningless on an Android device.

Second, while there is an `android.resource:` `Uri` scheme that you could use, few apps support it.

Third, while you could copy the raw resource to a file, then open the file, [support for that is fading away](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Your primary choices are:

- Copy the resource to a file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), then [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)
- Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which can serve your PDF straight from its raw resource (though I would recommend you put it in `assets/` instead)

Comment: So, I think that copy the resource to a file on internal storage is more easily and maybe you can write, how can I do that on this code? :)